# Issue in the Login code in C#

Tags: c#, .net

**I have modified my previously written code but still not able to find the flaw**....
I am trying to check Login using column names of DB as parameters in the code.
The If statement that I have provided does not seem to be working as the code always displays an Unsuccessful Login whereas the parameters are able to return the Database record on the console..(as shown in the link below).
Yet the control does not enter the **if statement...**

*[This is the code::](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hthbq.png)*

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String s1 = textBox1.Text;
        String s2 = textBox2.Text;

        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=register;Integrated Security=True");
            String sql = ("select Userid,Password from reg where Userid='" + s1 + "' and Password='" + s2 + "' ");
            cnn.Open();

            String userid="";
            String password="";

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,cnn);
           SqlDataReader reader  = cmd.ExecuteReader();



           if (reader.HasRows)
           {
               while(reader.Read())
               {
                   userid = reader.GetString(0);
                   password = reader.GetString(1);

                   Console.WriteLine(userid);
                   Console.WriteLine(password);
               }

        if((s1.Equals(userid)) && (s2.Equals(password)))
               {

                    MessageBox.Show("LOGIN SUCCESSFULLY DONE>>");
               }

               else
               {
                    MessageBox.Show("LOGIN UNSUCCESSFUL ....");
               }
           }
```

[Database Entry[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxt3u.png)

Comment: Not really the question you're asking, but I'd highly recommend getting into the habit of using parameterized queries. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx  Your approach is highly susceptible to a sql injection attack.

Comment: @OswaldVinny `String sql= ...` needs to be executed, otherwise it is just a plain string. Search in google about `SqlCommand`.

Comment: First, your conditional is checking your textboxes input against the literal strings "Userid" and "Password".  Second, you never execute your query (note that your `sql` variable never gets used). Third, I'm pretty sure that sql syntax won't work.  Fourth, look into using parameterized queries.  Don't concatenate strings to make your sql.  That is just asking for a sql injection attack.

Comment: You should also read about password hashing. Storing plaintext passwords in a database is a really bad idea.

Comment: yes @Roger Lipscombe am working that too...right now i need to fix the login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I wrote actually had no flaws in it. The problem here was run time during the entry of the data.Trailing white spaces are also being considered because of which the strings are not able to be matched successfully.Hence to resolve the problem I have used the trim() function.

This is the change  I made -

```
 String s1 = textBox1.Text.Trim();
        String s2 = textBox2.Text.Trim();

     //And further in the while loop
            userid = reader.GetString(0).Trim();
            password = reader.GetString(1).Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AND` in the `WHERE` clause instead of a comma:

```
String sql=("select userid,password from reg where Userid='"+s1+"' and Password='"+s2+"' ")
                                                                   ^^^
```

Then you need to **execute** the query:

```
string userid, password;

using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,cnn))
{
   cnn.Open();

   using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
      reader.Read();
      userid = reader.GetString(0);
      password = reader.GetString(1);
   }
}
```

**THEN** you use the values in the `if` statement:

```
if ((s1.Equals(userid)) && (s2.Equals(password)))
```

Comment: what do I initialize that userid & password with? I tried making it userid=(String)null....But it doesn't work..

Comment: Instead of `var`, use `string`. I updated my answer.

Comment: no sir I had tried that earlier.It says 'reader' cannot convert object to string....an explicit conversion exists.

Comment: an invalidoperation exception pops up.I tried to catch it...but didn't work...Is their no other way to fix this??

Comment: you have to understand what's going on with the code. If the exception is thrown from `reader.GetString()` then the SQL query probably didn't return any results. You can get the return value from `reader.Read()` that tells you if there is a row of data.

Comment: can you please check my code once again for the last time and trace out the possible reason for this problem...